# How to change menu icon onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is how i set up my toolbar (MainActivity).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

now i want to change the xml file to `main_notification_on` when i receive notification. This is what i want achieve

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            if(there is no new notification)
             { 
                   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); }
            else{
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_notification_on, menu);
                }
            return true;
        }
```

here is my `onMessageReceived` from `MyFirebaseMessagingService`

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
     String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
     showNotifications(title, message);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has the solution worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called invalidateOptionsMenu() along with  OnPrepareOptionsMenu(). Whenever invalidateOptionsMenu() is called then in the callback OnPrepareOptionsMenu() will be called.This is where you can make the change to your menu layout. The code goes something like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
     String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
     showNotifications(title, message);

     //send a broadcast from here and catch it in MainActivity
}
```

Now in OnReceive() of broadcast receiver in MainActivity use invalidateOptionsMenu():

```
@Override
OnReceive(){
invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Override the method OnPrepareOptionsMenu() in your MainActivity and change the layout there. Something on these lines:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_notification_on, menu);
  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, now i'm trying use your answer